# Styling polygon layer with symbols that indicates value of attribute of polygon?

Tags: polygon, symbology, style, qgis-3

[image: Currently shows only 1 icon for each polygon]

I want the same thing, but the number of dollars shown should indicate the value of the attribute of the polygon. For example one polygon may have 2 dollar icons indicating 200 (value of an attribute, say income) and another polygon shows 5 icons indicating a value of 500.

The symbols should be automatically generated indicating the rounded value of the attribute, and they should be in a single line.
I tried using the centroid fill with single marker, but could not understand which setting I need to play with to achieve this effect.

Answer (score 6):

Interesting idea! 
Building on your `Centroid fill` approach, it can be done like below.

(1) Select `Centroid fill`

(2) Select `Font marker`

(3) Click on `Data defined override` and (4) select `Edit`

(5) Expression is `rpad('', round("income", -2)/100, '$')`  ... (please note the first part is two single-quotation marks `''` without space in bewtween.)

[image]

Final image:

[image]

Comment: [@Kazuhito](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/84455/kazuhito), I am not surprised to see your answer =) Just a tiny hint, `"income"` is a column from the Attribute table of the polygon, should be a float or integer.

Comment: Thanks @Kazuhito! But I can't help but think about how to achieve this effect with symbols other than characters. I mentioned the dollar icon just as an example, but wanted a more presentable, customized icon. There is an option for data driven override for simple markers as well. Appreciate it if you could, if possible, guide me in the correct direction for this effect. I am sorry for replying after a while, I was travelling over the last week.

Comment: @AshokR Some font provides quite a lot of styles you can modify. But probably you have icons in mind you wish to use. Yes, I think it is also possible...in quite a different way, and I cannot answer it just by editing / updating this one. Would you post a new question? And it will be helpful if you could mention which icon (symbol) you would like to use (just an example).